# Why does flash work in Chrome even though flash is uninstalled flash on my machine?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, safari, webkit

After uninstalling flash on my mac I can no longer use flash in safari. That makes sense. But flash still works in chrome? Why is this? Does chrome have its own flash rendering engine baked in?

Comment: Yes, Chrome has its own install of the Flash Player packaged inside of it.  It will prefer to use this version rather than whichever might (or might not) be installed elsewhere on the machine.  You can disable it by navigating to chrome://plugins

Comment: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, google chrome does have the flash plug-in built in:

Link: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html

that link includes disabling also, but so does this one.

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/12/03/how-to-disable-chromes-built-in-flash-to-use-a-flash-beta-rele/